# Calling a function from a class within the class

Tags: python

EDIT: I assure you that everything is correctly indented when I run this through python. I assume the problem has to do with how I call p._x and p._y but I'm not sure why?

This is a problem I am having crazy amounts of difficulty with. It just doesn't make sense. I have to submit this through a program checker, so it checks the code and makes sure its correct. If its not correct it gives out a useless error report.

Ok so this is what I want to do:
I need to calculate the distance between two vectors(x,y).

This is the test case that the program will run:

```
foo = Point(1,2)
bar = Point(3,4)
foo.dist_to_point(bar) = 2.8...
```

This is the code I have:

```
import math
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
      self._x = x
      self._y = y


    def dist_to_point(self, p):
      a = self._x - p._x
      b = self._y - p._y
      c = math.sqrt(a**2+b**2)
      return c
```

and it doesn't work. **The error it gives me is this "you are trying to index into a point object. They are not lists or tuples - for point object p use p._x and p._y to access the required variables.**

Any ideas?

Comment: `dist_to_point` has bad indentation, it's a `Point` method so it needs 4 spaces indentation

Comment: Thats not the problem for in my program I assure you, I just made the mistake when trying to copy it into stackoverflow.

Comment: Either the program checker is wrong or your code is different. You aren't using any sort of indices in your code.

Comment: This may be in the program checker. Without knowing how it's written it is nearly impossible to help you.

Comment: probably your program checker is wrong, the code you posted works fine

Comment: You should contact the one that gave you the assignment and inform them the checker is wrong.

Comment: Why private (`_x` and `_y`)?

Comment: see http://pythonfiddle.com/calling-a-function/

Comment: What the code checker thinks you have done is probably something like this: `p = Point(0,1); print p[0]`.  It's telling you to instead do `p = Point(0,1); print p._x`.  If somewhere in your code you are doing anything related to the first example, that is your problem.  If you aren't, there's an issue with the checker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python requires all of your indentation to be the same. I see you're using a mixture of tabs and spaces, so your code won't even compile correctly. Here is the same code you have above, just with all of the indentation being two spaces instead of a mixture of tabs and spaces (it compiles and works!):

```
import math
class Point:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self._x = x
    self._y = y

  def dist_to_point(self, p):
    a = self._x - p._x
    b = self._y - p._y
    c = math.sqrt(a**2+b**2)
    return c


foo = Point(1,2)
bar = Point(3,4)
print(foo.dist_to_point(bar))
```

Pick tabs or spaces - don't use both. :)

Comment: I assure you it is really indented correctly in IDLE, its just I copied and pasted it into stackoverflow and it messed up my indention.

Comment: ...or, if you don't want to make copy-paste mistakes etc, like demonstrated in unedited question, just use spaces, full stop... YMMV

Comment: It does not work going through the program tester, which my question pertains to.

Comment: Well, we need to know what kind of program tester you are using. The above code correctly runs in python.

Comment: The course provider made it himself. This is the error it gives me "The error it gives me is this "you are trying to index into a point object. They are not lists or tuples - for point object p use p._x and p._y to access the required variables."

Comment: What does it mean "you are trying to index into a point object"?

Comment: @Ghozt: Using square brackets to access an item: `foo[0]` or `bar[1]`. Do you have *any* brackets in your source code (even in a comment)?

Comment: yeah there were other brackets. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wild guesses:

- Elsewhere, in code not shown, you are supposed to use a collection of points, but you use a single point.
- You are supposed to implement indexed access to point coordinates.

You should review the assignment.